Decoding and Extracting Data from complex string in base58
I want to extract the following information from a base58 encoded string:
{
"name": {
"type": "string",
"data": "PuppyPizza"
},
"symbol": {
"type": "string",
"data": "PUPPYPIZZA"
},
"uri": {
"type": "string",
"data": "https://cf-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmR4mMTi4PsoefT5YgwGGiQuBDA8V3yDDNyggt34E67WG5"
}
}
the encoded base58 string is as follows: 22WVW8SKNT2KRq1LB9nNfrqWJQUHMqrKr9GQLjEgDSF3yk2eddQtSxoEvJFzshvXKZameaosv6bHTUn8AKVaJ55MFyBUpvUyk29DuN7B22x3XKh3CmkUnKvDMWX19cXpKMredzTYGJJwKTn51CB7uW3n
I decoded this to HEX data:
181ec828051c07770a000000507570707950697a7a610a000000505550505950495a5a414700000068747470733a2f2f63662d697066732e636f6d2f697066732f516d52346d4d54693450736f6566543559677747476951754244413856337944444e796767743334453637574735
HEX to ASCII:
È(w
PuppyPizza
PUPPYPIZZAGhttps://cf-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmR4mMTi4PsoefT5YgwGGiQuBDA8V3yDDNyggt34E67WG5
as you can see the data is in it, but it's separated by ASCII symbols and I just can't figure out a way to extract the 3 parts I need, only the URL I can do easily. The thing is it's not always the same symbols separating the 3 parts, so I need to find a way to extract the correct 3 parts every time I run the script.
I'm building a monitor on pump.fun tokens and need to extract this data.
any help is much appreciated!

This is a pumpdotfun encoded create instruction?
import {
  BorshCoder,
} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { bs58 } from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";

const main = async () => {
  let base58Data =
    "22WVW8SKNT2KRq1LB9nNfrqWJQUHMqrKr9GQLjEgDSF3yk2eddQtSxoEvJFzshvXKZameaosv6bHTUn8AKVaJ55MFyBUpvUyk29DuN7B22x3XKh3CmkUnKvDMWX19cXpKMredzTYGJJwKTn51CB7uW3n";

  let buffer = Buffer.from(bs58.decode(base58Data));
  let coder = new BorshCoder(idl as any);
  let args = coder.instruction.decode(buffer);
  console.log(args);
};

main();

{
  name: 'create',
  data: {
    name: 'PuppyPizza',
    symbol: 'PUPPYPIZZA',
    uri: 'https://cf-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmR4mMTi4PsoefT5YgwGGiQuBDA8V3yDDNyggt34E67WG5'
  }
}

Repo: https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk

thanks a lot! But probably an insanely stupid question, but is this TS? and how can I run this in TS never used that :)

ha np, yes it is TS...
npm i
then
npx ts-node examples/events/index.ts and lmk

I keep running into errors. I installed anchor and I'm running the script you provided with some small tweaks (using the pump.fun idl) and I'm getting the following error:
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'option' in publicKey
but also just running your script is giving me errors with the {idl as any"
thanks!

What version of node are you running?  node -v, im running v20.10.0

v20.13.1
and anchor-cli v0.30.0

Did you clone the repo or npm install?

Thank you so much! I got it working :)
